# Storing validator in MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation

I'd like to have a flexible schema in Mongo, but would also like to enforce a schema for subsequent updates.  Is it possible to store the validation in the document like the following?
I have tried this, but can't seem to convert the string into a Joi object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d5dce1fc87899b2b3c2def"),
    "name" : {
        "validator" : "Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required()",
        "value" : "Bob" 
    },
    "email" : {
        "validator" : "Joi.string().email()",
        "value" : "bob@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where (node, mongodb...) and when (create, update, read...) do you want the validation to happen?

Comment: Probably in node as I expect it would be more flexible. On update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, storing executable code in a database is not a good idea. What will you do when you realize a validator function which is already stored in a billion documents needs to be modified? What if someone manages to insert a document with validation code which does more malicious stuff than just validating?

I would really recommend you to determine the type of the document and the appropriate validation routine for each type in node.js.

But when you insist on having executable code for each document in the document itself, you can run that code in node.js using the [vm.runInContext(object.validator, object) method](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runincontext_code_context_filename). Keep in mind that this requires access to the whole document in node.js, so you can not do partial updates. Also keep in mind that, as I said, **it might not be a very good idea**.

Comment: I don't expect that I'd let anyone write their own Validators. Probably just select and configure a dozen pre existing ones.  I'm not expecting that any two documents would be exactly the same (although I'm sure there would be some overlap), so difficult to determine a 'type'.

Comment: @user1074891 Even when you do not *expect* that you let people insert their own code, you are opening yourself to code injections due to the slightest programming mistake on your side. Any user-supplied string you put into the validation code would be a possible security vulnerability.

Comment: Are you saying the potential impact of this type of abuse is greater when using vm.runInContext, or are you just highlighting this risk in general?

Comment: @user1074891 The risk in general.

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming **Mongo 3.2 version** they are going to add [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document-validation/) ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewjamesmorgan/document-validation-in-mongodb-32)).

It will work in a different way and looking at your requirements it looks like it is possible to achieve what you want. It is possible to specify the type of the field, check the existence and pass through regex.

Here is a little bit about validation. You can specify validation rules for each collection, using [validator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#validator) option using almost all mongo query operators (except `$geoNear`, `$near`, `$nearSphere`, `$text`, and `$where`).

To create a new collection with a validator, use:

```
db.createCollection("your_coll", {
  validator: { `your validation query` }
})
```

To add a validator to the existing collection, you can add the validator:

```
db.createCollection("your_coll", {
  validator: { `your validation query` }
})
```

Validation work only on insert/update, so when you create a validator on your old collection, the previous data will not be validated (you can write application level validation for a previous data). You can also specify [validationLevel](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#rel-notes-validationlevel) and [validationAction](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#rel-notes-validationaction) to tell what will happen if the document will not pass the validation.

If you try to insert/update the document with something that fails the validation, (and have not specified any strange validationLevel/action) then you will get an error on `writeResult` (sadly enough the error does not tell you what failed and you get only default `validation failed`):

```
WriteResult({
   "nInserted" : 0,
   "writeError" : {
      "code" : 121,
      "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
   }
})
```